# Cannot get jmeter-plugins to work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am a Jmeter/Java newbie and downloaded the ATLANTBH Jmeter pluginds and tried to use the JSON path extractor.. It just throws me this error

```
meter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:313)
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.extractJSONPath(JSONPathExtractor.java:56)
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.process(JSONPathExtractor.java:80)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:737)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:439)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could any one explain what i might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download and install pre-compiled package from jmeter-plugins.org, it will containvall required libs